# How to make a complete NTP call using several servers?

Tags: python, ntp

I need to independently check the current time (and, incidentally, cross check with system provided time) and I wanted to use the NTP protocol for that.

There is an NTP module ([`ntplib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/)) which allows to query **one** NTP server:

```
>>> import ntplib
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(ntplib.NTPClient().request('europe.pool.ntp.org', version=3).tx_time)
'Wed Nov 18 17:17:16 2015'
```

I would like to use the NTP ability to combine the responses from several NTP servers to get an [optimum response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol):

> [the NTP protocol] uses a modified version of Marzullo's algorithm to
>   select accurate time servers and is designed to mitigate the effects
>   of variable network latency.

What would be the right way in Python (ideally 3.x) to leverage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the right way in Python (ideally 3.x) to leverage that?

**Basically, you would have to implement Marzullo's algorithm in Python.**

Once you have queried two servers, how are you going to determine which clock is closer to an atomic clock?

Determining the "optimum response"(a.k.a. most accurate time source) is tricky business.

What you are looking for is an NTP `implementation`, unless you feel like rolling your own in python.

The NTP Protocol discussed on the wiki page is talking about the NTP [Reference Implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_implementation). This consists of an ntp daemon running on all your servers. The ntp daemons keep track of remote reference servers, and which ones are alive, and are most accurate. Ntp daemon then slews or steps your clock to match the remote clock.

**Perhaps the easiest way** for you to achieve what you want, is to run an ntp daemon(i.e. use the Reference Implementation) on your server in Client mode. In your ntp.conf, list all of the time servers that you are trying to use to find that "optimum response" from. When you have ntpd running, the daemon will determine the lowest stratum, most accurate and available reference server for you.

All you need to do is `ntpq -p`, and the remote server with the most accurate time will be the server with the asterisk next to it.

Here's some sample output:

```
    remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l  96h   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
*ns2.example.com 10.193.2.20      2 u  936 1024  377   31.234    3.353   3.096
```

Comment: Thanks, I have NTP running on the platform but (to make a long story short) I need to check the time independently. BTW *the remote server with the most accurate time will be the server with the asterisk next to it.* is not exactly correct - this is the server which is taken into account for core time calculations, the others are participating as well, according to the link I mentioned in my question.

Comment: WoJ:  What you are referring to is Active Symmetric mode(peer mode). I was correct, as I was talking about client mode. I can update the answer to reflect that. Furthermore, are you just looking for someone to write a python-based  NTP implementation for you, or are you trying to develop your own?

Comment: If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm, the correction vs local time is calculated against several servers (and then used to modify the local clock, slowly or one-shot). I am not interested in an implementation of a NTP server but of an NTP client which will take into account queries to several servers and not just one as `ntplib` does. This said, since I did not find any such implementation I will write my own (poor) one which will discard statistically suspicious servers.

Comment: Yes WoJ, NTP must poll all remote servers to figure out which one is the best time source for client mode.... But not all NTP modes compute an average of the times on remote servers used for syncing. Only peer mode does this. Google NTP modes.